# Qt / c++ float без экспоненты

Tags: c++, qt, float

Всем привет, имеются две переменные типа float и int. При попытке их перемножить, в некоторых случаях появляются значения с экспонентой, например:

```
0.5 * 4690678 = 2.34534e+06;
0.5 * 2161017 = 1.08051e+06;
```

Все значения нужно поместить в QString. Каким образом можно избавиться от экспоненты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде решил проблему.

```
QString::number(a * b, 'g', 10)
```

В результате получается ответ без экспоненты.